# Should I add google-play service location dependencies or not if I had copy the google-service.json file into the Android Project

Tags: android, json, firebase, dependencies

I had download my google-service.json file through Firebase Console and the file have been added into my android project file. My question is, if i want to do a fusedlocation on my app, I still need to import google-service:location in dependencies or not? My dependencies for firebase is version 10.0.1, hence if i put dependencies for my latest version google-play service 11.0.0, it will conflict with my firebase version dependencies.

Here is my buil.gradle (app)

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 25
    buildToolsVersion "26.0.0"
    defaultConfig {
       applicationId "com.example.akmalnizarrosle.schoolbustracking"
       minSdkVersion 19
       targetSdkVersion 25
       versionCode 1
       versionName "1.0"
       testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }

    buildTypes {
      release {
        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
}
    }

    dependencies {
compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
androidTestCompile('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2', 
    {
    exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
})
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.3.1'
compile 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.0-alpha7'
compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:10.0.1'
compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database:10.0.1'
testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
}



apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, if you want to use location services, you need to include the library for that API.  You should use the same version for the Firebase and Google Play libraries.  Either 11.0.0 or 10.0.1 is okay, just make them all the same.  It's best to use the latest:

```
compile 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.2'

compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:11.0.0'
compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database:11.0.0'
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:11.0.0'
```

Comment: My current dependencies for firebase were auto added using firebase assistant in android studioand its 10.0.1 version. If i want to use google play latest version 11.0.0, I just renumbered the firebase dependencies or i need to update using sdk manager or firebase assistant?

Comment: Just renumber the Firebase dependencies to 11.0.0

Comment: Tq sir. I done with your solution. Do you have any thread that you answer on how I can save the location data (lat, long) from fusedLocation into Firebase database under registered auth user login?